# Change text direction to become right-to-left in R Markdown

Tags: r, markdown, right-to-left

I have a fully functioning RMD template which generates nice reports in English.

(The RMD stands for R Markdown file. Basically its an interactive template r file, which can receive input from another r file many times. as any given input is passed, the template calculates some functions on the input and saves an HTML report corresponding to the outputs you specify.)

In addition, I need to make another version which look beautiful in Hebrew instead. simply replacing the text works fine. However, The main a issue with it is that the text is aligned Left-to-right (compatible with English) while I need to turn it to Right-to-left.

I am sure there is some simple way to do it, but I haven't found it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please explain a bit about RMD templates for those who might know R, but not be familiar with your exact problem.

Comment: Have you tried `pandoc`'s `dir` variable (with value `rtl`)? It is available for `pandoc` >= 1.18. Maybe it requires `to=html`. See doc [here](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#language-variables).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add css options to your Rmd template file. For example:

```
---
title: חוכמה
output: html_document
---
<style>
h1 {
  direction: rtl;
}
p {
  direction: rtl;
}
</style>

הספר הוא ידידו הטוב של האדם
```

Render this document with `rmarkdown::render("Template.Rmd")` for a result like this:

[image]

Option `direction: rtl;` specifies text direction right to left.

`p` in :

```
p {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Specifies direction for text in "**p**aragraphs".
`h1` in:

```
h1 {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Specifies direction for level 1 header (it's your title and header that starts with 1 `#`). For direction to work with all headers (eg, `#`, `##`, `###`) you should use:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Comment: great answer!  could you please expend more about the meaning of h1 and p? how do you access the titles? 
ומה עם הכלב?

Comment: @PoGibas is there a specification for `rtl` bullets too? I'd be grateful if you could post a link to a list/guide on this subject!